# What is the most efficient way to validate a compressed ZIP file when using ZIPFoundation

Tags: ios, swift, zipfoundation

[ZIPFoundation](https://github.com/weichsel/ZIPFoundation)

Is there a method similar to validate that can be used for this purpose?

A method looks like this：

```
func validateZipFile(at zipFileURL: URL) -> Bool {
    guard let archive = Archive(url: zipFileURL, accessMode: .read) else { return false }
    let validationResult = archive.validate()
    return validationResult == .success
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[ZipUtilities](https://github.com/NSProgrammer/ZipUtilities) solve the problem.

According to [the specification for the .ZIP file format](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/APPNOTE/APPNOTE-6.3.9.TXT), the `end of the central directory record` can be used for verification.

NOZUnzipper will perform format validation on a .ZIP file before attempting to unzip it.

```
- (BOOL)unzipThingsAndReturnError:(out NSError **)error
{
    NSAssert(![NSThread isMainThread]); // do this work on a background thread

    NOZUnzipper *unzipper = [[NOZUnzipper alloc] initWithZipFile:zipFilePath];
    if (![unzipper openAndReturnError:error]) {
        return NO;
    }

    if (nil == [unzipper readCentralDirectoryAndReturnError:error]) {
        return NO;
    }

    __block NSError *enumError = nil;
    [unzipper enumerateManifestEntriesUsingBlock:^(NOZCentralDirectoryRecord * record, NSUInteger index, BOOL * stop) {
        NSString *extension = record.name.pathExtension;
        if ([extension isEqualToString:@"jpg"]) {
            *stop = ![self readImageFromUnzipper:unzipper withRecord:record error:&enumError];
        } else if ([extension isEqualToString:@"json"]) {
            *stop = ![self readJSONFromUnzipper:unzipper withRecord:record error:&enumError];
        } else {
            *stop = ![self extractFileFromUnzipper:unzipper withRecord:record error:&enumError];
        }
    }];

    if (enumError) {
        *error = enumError;
        return NO;
    }

    if (![unzipper closeAndReturnError:error]) {
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

So, it's simple to use NOZUnzipper class to open and read the central directory of a ZIP file.

If any errors occur during this process, function returns false.

```
func validateZipFile(at zipFileURL: URL) -> Bool {
    let unzipper = NOZUnzipper.init(zipFile: zipFileURL.path)
    do {
        try unzipper.open()
        try unzipper.readCentralDirectory()
    } catch let error{
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```